# Vs2017 / C# weird debugger behavior

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am being plagued by weird behavior in a debug build of a C# project (target .Net Framework 4.7.2).

1. The following code return false.

```
var wHasOvernightShifts = this.ScheduleSegments.Any(
    x => x.SegmentTypeId == eSegmentType.Schedule 
         && !x.IsDeleted 
         && x.ShiftDate == pShiftDate 
         && x.StartTime.Value.DayOfWeek != x.FinishTime.Value.DayOfWeek);
```

I know this to be the wrong answer. When I evaluate the RHS in Quick Watch (at the same point with the same data) the same code returns true. Step back the debugger and re-execute the statement returns false again. (n.b. All properties referenced have no side affects).

2. I also have a method which seems to execute but returns null. A breakpoint inside the method is never triggered. Attempts to step into the function are ignored. The breakpoint says that it will not be triggered as the module is  not yet loaded. However, a few lines higher in the source code a function from that same module behaves normally (w.r.t. debugging and expected function).

If I perform a clean and rebuild then everything behaves as expected. Note that a rebuild by itself is insufficient.

In case 2, following a clean/rebuild, the method returns a non-empty collection and the breakpoint inside it works, as does step-into.

It looks like the incremental part of the compiler is broken, or the execution environment has just forgotten that the module is loaded.

Has anyone else hit similar problems? Is there a simple solution (apart from clean/rebuild)?

n.b. I have turned off "Enable Just My Code" and turned on "Require source files to exactly match the original version" in an attempt to cure this problem - no luck.

Comment: Does this only happen when you intentionally step the debugger back to enumerate `ScheduleSegments` again?

Comment: Do you have an override for `ToString` in any of the relevant classes?  Your debugger will call `ToString` (by default) to format values for presentation, while your actual code won't do that.

Comment: What is `this.ScheduleSegments`? Is it a list or a query? Examining Linq statements in the debugger is notoriously tricky due to deferred execution.

Comment: 1. ScheduleSegments is an Observable collection .

Comment: 2. All my classes oerride ToString() so that I can view them in debug mode.

Comment: 3. This problem occurs with a debug build even if I don't stop at a break point. The execution is wrong. I only stepped back to confirm that the original wrong answer was still occuring.

Comment: @PeterWilson Do any of those `ToString()` implementations have side effects?

Comment: No. Simple string concatenation using string.Format

Comment: @PeterWilson Okay then, do any of the properties referenced in those `ToString()` implementations have side effects?  (It would be easier to help you if your question contained a [mcve])

Comment: No, As far as I can tell there are no side effects (all simple getters).. My chances of producing a reproducible example from this are slim to none. This part of the application contains 4 model classes each with a partial class implementation. They are held in 2 files of 1,000 lines of code each. (one of which is generated from the DB). My feeling is the effect will go away with a smaller setup.

Comment: I believe I've found the cause of problem #2. The release and debug build of that module were being built in the same directory. Switching between builds without a full rebuild meant that the wrong module was being loaded. It does not begin to explain problem #1.

Comment: There is a high probability that the problem is a debug exception caused by a feature of the code.    Can you share an small example with us and then we can reproduce the issue in our side?

Comment: Jack J: There is no chance of producing a small sample. I believe  the problem was the mixed release/debug modules (now fixed)..If Quick watch is using a JIT to compile the code then it is quite plausible that it was getting a different (and correct) answer from the original code.

Answer (score 1):

It has been several weeks now since I updated the project to make sure that each configuration builds into a separate directory. The problem seems to have gone away.

I am pretty sure that this was the solution to the problem.